# How to deal with a System.InvalidOperationExcpetion in Dictionary's TryGetValue method

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, exception

I'm doing this to look up for specific key inside the dictionary with the same row id_d i want to find and it really works great with keys that really exist, but it whatever throws me the exception when a key doesn't match the query criteria in the parameters value.

```
if(sentences.TryGetvalue(values = (from keys in sentences where keys.key.id_d == rows.id_d selesck keys.Key).First(), out listOf))
```

do you know how can i resolve this issue, i mean, just avoiding those null references from values and continuing without being stopped by the exception.

an example would be something like  this:

```
if(sentences.TryGetValue(values = (from keys in sentences where keys.key.id_d == rows.id_d selesck keys.Key).First(), out listOf))
{

     //do whatever  
}
else 
{
   //if the 'value' query doesn't match the criteria, don't do anything    
}
```

Comment: Why would you do a LINQ search in a dictionary and then use TryGetValue to get the value which you've just found? Also you didn't explain what error you're getting. I'm assuming there isn't one that mathces and `First()` expects to get results.

Comment: Who is actually throwing the exception? Is it the LINQ query or the `TryGetValue`? Separate it out so you can see what's going on. And `values`? `selesck`? Please post an example that actually compiles.

Comment: well because i'm iterating over a list that  have rows which doesn't match at all the key value of the dictionary and what only can match it , is  id_d property of each key value, so if the value that is already on the rows list, doesn't match the id_d property from the dictionary, I just want to avoid and continue with the next element

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you're using a dictionary if the `TKey` isn't actually the key you're going to use to look up a value - you're missing out on the constant time lookup. I can only assume you're using it elsewhere.

If you want to find a value based on a key predicate, you can just select the value (rather than the key) and return `FirstOrDefault` - `TryGetValue` isn't required. This will return the default value (likely `null`, unless `TValue` is a value type) in the case that no match is found:

```
var result = 
    (from pair in sentences 
    where pair.Key.id_d == rows.id_d 
    select pair.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Though this might read better if you used method syntax throughout:

```
var result = sentences
    .Where(x => x.Key == rows.id_d)
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you!, i'm gonna try this. So, you might be right about me looking  up for a key value i already checked for, but why i'm really trying to do is  iterate over a list of rows which each row wouldn't  match at all the row's key criteria, just the id_d property of each row would do it and since in my list is being filled automatically with many rows,  I  can only avoid that that aren't in the key field  by the id_d property